# Django forget password

Tags: python, django, passwords

I follow this code:

http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/apr/09/django-reset-password/

but when I run I have this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_reset
  161.             form.save(**opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
  260.             email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  170.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  146.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  135.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  43.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  49.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
  157.     return Template(source, origin, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  125.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_string
  153.     return parser.parse()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  274.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in autoescape
  498.     nodelist = parser.parse(('endautoescape',))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  274.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in do_block
  190.     nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  274.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in url
  1286.                 kwargs[name] = parser.compile_filter(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_filter
  353.         return FilterExpression(token, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  570.                                       "from '%s'" % (token[upto:], token))

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/password/reset/
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'uid,'
```

How I can fix this error?

Edit:

I change this to `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}` but I have this error:

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': u'1', u'token': u'3ho-bd57a871a2fe3a4987ef'}' not found.
```

?

Comment: what version of Django do you have? It sounds like it's a problem with the comma between `uidb36=uid` and `token=token` in your template

Comment: I use from django 1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the comma between `uidb36=uid` and `token=token` in your template. In Django 1.5, [the comma's separating the url arguments aren't supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

> In Django 1.5, the behavior of the url template tag will change ... The new library also drops support for the comma syntax for separating arguments to the url template tag.

Comment: I remove the comma but occoured this error:`'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.` What I do?

Answer (score 0):

If faced with the `'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.` simply put the view/function that is the first argument of the url template tag in double quotes.